# Node: 'Best Practice' of js files using other js files

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is the scenario:

Main.js:

```
var one = require(./one.js);
var two = require(./two.js);

two.foo();
```

one.js:

```
module.exports = {
  foo: function () {
    console.log("this was called by two");
  }
};
```

two.js:

```
module.exports = {
  foo: function () {
    one.foo();
  }
};
```

I'm calling one of two's functions in main which then calls one's function, which then logs. Currently, I get an error in two.js saying "one is not defined." The goal of this was to break up a giant js file into smaller ones that all use each other in some way. If this is not possible please let me know.

So far the only fixes I can think of are:

1. requiring one.js in two.js
2. passing an instance of one into two in some form of init function
3. some global instance of one?

Comment: In general, each module/file should list its own requirements. Since `main.js` doesn't currently use `one`, it has no need to require `one.js`. While `two.js` does depend on it (#1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to require one.js in two.js, like you said. Every file that accesses another file needs to require that file.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

Main.js:

```
var two = require(./two);
two.foo();
```

one.js:

```
module.exports = {
  foo: function () {
    console.log("this was called by two");
  }
};
```

two.js:

```
var one = require(./one);
module.exports = {
  foo: function () {
    one.foo();
  }
};
```